# What do appleeventsd and AppleIDAuthAgent do?

Tags: activity-monitor, macos, launchd

I looked in the activity monitor to clarify what are those processes and started with alphabetic order. I know different resources where many processes are described. But `appleeventsd` and `AppleIDAuthAgent` are not the case even for goole search - only issues results were found without explaining what does these processes stands for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`appleeventsd` is the Apple Events daemon, which handles cross-application interaction. It is the underlying basis for AppleScript amongst many other things.

AppleIDAuthAgent is "[used to check the validity of AppleID certificates](https://discussions.apple.com/message/16760135#16760135)".

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe that. Even the name already implies that it has to do with "Apple IDs" and why would it connect to setup.icloud.com? There are no cert infos at that address. It may __also__ verify certs among many other things, but if take a look [at the traffic](http://klurl.nl/?u=UWogbM) it sends out, this doesn't even look close to anything checking validity of certs.

Comment: Your Apple ID private key is stored locally in a certificate in Keychain Access. The AppleIDAuthAgent process confirms the validity of the local certificate with the server. iCloud is an integral part of Apple ID and vice-versa, so it makes sense that an iCloud domain would be involved. The response includes things such as "VettingStatus" and "ValidForInterval" which would align perfectly with validating a certificate.

Comment: Private keys are not stored in certificates, public keys are. And where would this AppleID cert be in my keychain? I don't see any. Also there are common mechanism to validate certificates (OCSP for example), so why is Apple not using those (as they are in fact for all other certs). Also I see on keychain item that carries AppleIDAuthAgent in its access list (well, public certs have no access list of course, they are public, but I see no public AppleID cert)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/4t6Gtoi.jpg